# Who accessed hive tables in last 1 month

Tags: hive, hdfs

I want to know who accessed hive tables in last one month. Audit logs are disabled and there is no security layer. Please help!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check it.

Comment: may be https://thisdataguy.com/2017/06/23/extracting-queries-from-hive-logs/

Comment: thank you for the link! Although it did not solve the complete problem, but I can surely tweak with the code and get my desired output. :)